# Combobox with javascript values not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ipad, combobox

I have this Javascript

```
$(function () {
var $select = $(".comboboxValues");
for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
}
});
```

on this HTML element

```
<td class="imageClass">                                  
     <select class="comboboxValues select"></select>
</td>
```

with this CSS

```
.comboboxValues
{
    font-family:Segoe UI;
    text-align:center;
}
.select
    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        border: 0px;
        outline: 0px;
        border-bottom : 1px solid #6F8393;
        color: #384046;
        background: transparent;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -webkit-padding-start: 10px;
        -moz-padding-start: 10px;
        -webkit-padding-end: 10px;
        -moz-padding-end:10px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
```

This code works to fill a combobox with values on desktop and mobile android, but not on iPad.

Why is this not working on iPad and how can I solve this?

Comment: by "not working", I mean that on iPad the combobox comes up empty, with no options to select from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, but still do not know why this is working. I just wrote a different Javascript:

```
function fillComboboxValues() {
var comboboxCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('comboboxValues_iPad');
for (var j = 0; j < comboboxCollection.length; j++) {
    var select = comboboxCollection[j];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = i;
        select.add(option, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

And now it works perfect.